# LocaleMiddleware error when django_language cookie is set

Tags: django, internationalization, middleware

I want to use LocaleMiddleware to obtain the user preferred language in the template tier, showing different content for each language. According to django documentation, LocaleMiddleware does the following:

- First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL. This is only performed when you are using the i18n_patterns function in your root URLconf. See Internationalization: in URL patterns for more information about the language prefix and how to internationalize URL patterns.
- Failing that, it looks for a django_language key in the current user's session.
- Failing that, it looks for a cookie. The name of the cookie used is set by the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME setting. (The default name is django_language.)
- Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header until it finds one with available translations.
- Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.

It seems to work right when it uses the Accept-Language header. However, when I visit the set_language redirect, LocaleMiddleware starts failing with the following error:

```
AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_info'
```

If I exclude the LocaleMiddleware from the middlewares list or clear the browser cookies, the error doesn't appear anymore till I go again to the set_language redirect.

This is my configuration:

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('es', 'Español'),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

And the following pattern to the set_language redirect in urls.py:

```
(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

I've read some information to similar errors and bugs, but none of them solve my problem. Any clues?

Comment: I've discovered something interesting. Maybe it is because of my development machine. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Django 1.4.It works right when I test it with the root user, maybe it is something related to my installation permissions, I installed Django using PIP.

Comment: Try looking further at the stack trace of the error, so you can see which kind of object is missing an "_info" attribute... if you trace it back long enough, you'll find your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is Django way of saying "Translations not found for the requested language."

Have you ran compilemessages?